# File I/O in CLion IDE

Tags: c, file-io, clion

I am using CLion IDE for coding in C, and I had blocked in sth.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("address.txt", "r+");
    if(f == NULL){
        printf("File Open Error!");
        return 0;
    }

    char str[100][100];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++){
        fscanf(f, "%s", str[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++){
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CLion is telling me the "File Open Error".
So, I tried on DEV C++, and worked successfully.
I have no idea for this problem

Answer (score 0):

`r+` mode mean that file should exists, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Because of you not use absolute file path, then
program search file in current directory,
`Dev C++` and `CLion` obviously generate `exe` files in different
directories, in one of them `address.txt` exists, in another not.